# Oracle JET Single Page Application without Starter-Template

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, oracle-jet

Over the last week I tried to create a single page application without using the template provided by Oracle. My goal is to load the modules by clicking on simple headers or divs.

I know that OJ-Module and the CoreRouter are needed, but nothing I’ve tried so far has worked.

Maybe someone can give me some hints on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am trying similar methods and it is the best way of getting hang od the syntax, variables and the structure.

I created projects of all the 4 templates in different folders. Each one serves as a reference on how to implement a specific set of features like CSS, behaviors in my new app, created out of the blank template.

I also created a demo project. This project contains the specific element from cookbook I am trying to understand (one or two at a time and not more) and then implement the learning in the blank template, which I started filling already. The demo project keeps getting erased and recreated in my case.. You can choose to retain different demo projects if you need.

Most important will be the understanding of concepts like the busyContext, dataBinding, ResponsiveUI, Require, AMD, ojModule, inter-module interactions and the creation of events, views and viewMdels. Once you get past the initial hiccups, the APi docs are a great assistance in helping you programmatically control the entire behavior of the application features.

BTW: Do not remember the css variables. I think it is a bad idea to maintain so much material in your mind, which could otherwise be easily referenced in a document. You only need to know which documents have what content..